# How to remove trailing zeroes from Pandas Datetime Index (reformat as per wish)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing

I have a Pandas dataframe with datetime index which gives me 9 decimal points after the second. I only need till ms. How do I get rid of the extra trailing zeroes and round off?
[image: Dataframe]

Thanks in advance.I tried

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame(alldata)
all_data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['time'],format='%YYYY-%mm-%DD; %H:%M:%S.%.4f')
all_data = all_data.set_index('time')
```

As suggested by Jezrael:

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame(alldata)
all_data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['time']).dt.floor('L')
# all_data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['time'],format='%H:%M:%SS.SSSS')
all_data = all_data.set_index('time')
```

The output is:
[image: Floor]

Also I tried:

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame(alldata)
all_data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['time']).dt.round('L')
# all_data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['time'],format='%H:%M:%SS.SSSS')
all_data = all_data.set_index('time')
```

The output is

[image: round]

I want to get rid of these zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is round values after converting to datetimes:

```
all_data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['time']).dt.round('L')
```

Or you can also use floor:

```
all_data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['time']).dt.floor('L')
```

Comment: The round and floor both work the same way, but the zeroes are still there

Comment: @Rambopartyush - Can you add output to question with zeros? Not sure if understand.

Comment: @Rambopartyush - output are strings datetimes? Because if datetimes I think it is default display.

Comment: Yes they are datetime64[ns]. Can I change the format somehow?

Comment: @Rambopartyush - Why? What is reason for it?

Comment: For easy visualization. If I want to store it in a CSV or something.